# Uncaught runtime error: null is not an object (evaluating 'dispatcher.useState') when using react component from library with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yarnpkg, react-library

I am trying to break my code into separate packages to modularize my react application; doing so requires me to create react components in a separate the library that manages state using `useState`.

However, when leveraging the library's component in the react app, I receive this error:

```
null is not an object (evaluating 'dispatcher.useState')
useState@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:7493:24
Counter@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6017:65
renderWithHooks@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:22612:31
mountIndeterminateComponent@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25896:32
```

Here is my setup:

**React Library**
— *package.json*

```
{
    "name": "lib-five",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "./dist/cjs/index.js",
    "module": "./dist/esm/index.js",
    "types": "./dist/esm/index.d.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "prepare": "npm run build",
        "build": "yarn build:esm && yarn build:cjs",
        "build:esm": "tsc",
        "build:cjs": "tsc --module commonjs --outDir dist/cjs"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/react": "^18.2.48",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "typescript": "^5.3.3"
    },
    "peerDependencies": {
        "react": ">=16"
    },
    "files": [
        "dist"
    ]
}
```

*Counter.tsx*

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export const Counter: React.FC<{}> = () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0)

    const increment = () => setCount((c) => c + 1)
    const decrement = () => setCount((c) => c - 1)

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Counter</h1>
            <p>Count: { count }</p>
            <button onClick={ increment}>Increment</button>
            <button onClick={ decrement }>Decrement</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

*index.ts*

```
import { Counter } from './Counter'

export { Counter }
```

**React App (using the library)** — *package.json*

```
{
    "name": "uselibtest",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
        "@types/node": "^16.18.68",
        "@types/react": "^18.2.47",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.18",
        "lib-five": "file:../lib-five",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "typescript": "^4.9.5",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

*App.tsx*

```
import React
import { Counter } from 'lib-five'

function App() {

    return (
        <div style={ containerStyle }>

            <Counter />

        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```